# Entity Framework 4.3 Migrations move existing data

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF Code First 4.3 Migrations to update my database scheme. Now I have the following situation: table A needs to be removed, table B must be created and the data of table A must be copied (along with some other data) to table B. I do not have access to the `DbContext` in the `DbMigration` class, my question is how to implement this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In migration `Up` method of your migration you can use `Sql` method to define any SQL you need so if you use explicit migration you can put data migration code between creating Table B and removing Table A.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have an example how to copy for example an integer from table A to table B using the `Sql()` function?

Comment: So you don't know how to use SQL? You must have much more detailed description of migration logic to achieve that.

Comment: I found some more info, didn't know it was possible to copy data using a single SQL query. Still too bad the DbContext isn't available in DbMigration :)

Comment: It cannot be available during migration because database doesn't contain changes required for your current context and your current context doesn't match your original database - for example you already don't have TableA in context so how could you use it to load that data?